# Prevent autorotate for one view controller ios7?

Tags: ios, rotation, ios7

My app can autorotate but I need one of the views to only show in portrait mode and don't know how to achieve this. 
I tried this (among other things) but the view in question still rotates:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{            
    return NO;
}

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

This solution explains how to control orientation on individual view controllers, provided they are managed by a navigation controller.

In Xcode 5, create a new file of type "Objective-C category", set it's "Category" to "rotation" and choose "UINavigationController" as "Category on".

A new file couple will appear in the project, having the following names:
UINavigationController+rotation.h
UINavigationController+rotation.m

In the .m file, write the following code:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self topViewController] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

This way, the navigation controller will let the current top view controller determine the orientation policy.

Then, in each specific view controller that is managed by the navigation controller, you can override the two orientation-related methods.

For instance, if a specific view controller shall appear in portrait orientation only:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{            
    return NO;
}

 - (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Make sure that the desired orientation is one of those set in the project deployment info.
Hope this is sufficiently detailed and can be of help.

Answer (score 6):

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` will work if you present your view controller as a modal view controller.  It won't work if you present it as part of a navigation controller stack.  If you want your view presented modally but inside a navigation controller (to have navigation items, for instance) the solution I did was to subclass `UINavigationController` and override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods on my subclass.

Comment: @rkh You need code to make a subclass that overrides one function?

Comment: No, I just meant to explain your solution to Victor "in code" since he seems like a new user... I am good :)

Comment: could you give me a example to do it?