# iOS - Force YouTube video in Landscape through UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api, modalviewcontroller

I have an app which only supports Portrait mode.
In order to play YouTube video in fullscreen forcing Landscape mode, I tried presenting a modal view controller containing a web view which automatically plays.

For such vc I've implemented:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Moreover, in the RootViewController (which is a TabBarViewController):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

    if(/*modal view controller with web view is open*/) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

But it does not work, the video rotates and from that point on dismissing the modal vc from landscape mode the entire app remains in landscape.

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks, DAN

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method instead:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}
```

Comment: With that method the video correctly opens in Landscape (left) but when I rotate the device in Portrait the app as well as the video rotate too.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to container UIWebView to rotate but not the video inside it.

When your container rotates, your inner things like YouTube video rotates with it. If there is anyway to solve this, you have to rotate your video on the reverse direction at rotation time, so it will look like it didn't rotate at all.

So something like this: (Code is not complete, but you can get the idea, apply 90 degree rotation.)

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                              duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {   // Rotate to landscape  
 self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480.0, 320.0);   
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
      CGAffineTransform transform = self.view.transform;

     // Set the center point of the view to the center point of the window's content area.      
     self.view.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 240.0); 
     // Rotate the view 90 degrees around its new center point.
     transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (M_PI / 2.0));
     self.view.transform = transform;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, actually if it would be a better solution I don't want the container to rotate: all the app must remain in Portrait and the only thing which should rotate and always be displayed ONLY in Landscape is the player. Is it feasible or I should go with the solution you proposed?

Comment: so then you do the other way around. Keep the container stable and rotate the player. Here's how to block autorotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601235/prevent-autorotate-for-one-view-controller-ios7

Comment: in this way the web view rotates but when the video starts it opens a modal view with the player, which is not affected by such rotation.. any idea?